# Parsing a sequence of expressions using yacc

Tags: parsing, yacc, fsyacc

I am trying to parse a sequence of expressions without delimiters in order to be able to parse ML/F# style function invocations:

```
myfunc expr1 expr2 expr3
```

However, the sequence of expressions is giving me a list of shift/reduce conflicts.

My guess is that the conflicts are caused by the recursive nature of my grammar, but I don't know how to fix these conflicts.

My (simplified) precedence rules and grammar looks like this:

```
/* Lowest precedence */
%left PLUS
%left TIMES
%left LPAR
/* Highest precedence */

Expr: 
  | CSTINT                                { CstI $1                   }
  | LPAR Expr RPAR                        { $2                        }
  | Expr TIMES Expr                       { Prim("*", $1, $3)         }
  | Expr PLUS Expr                        { Prim("+", $1, $3)         }
  | NAME ExprList                         { Call(Var $1, $2)          }

ExprList:
  |                                      { []                        }
  | Expr ExprList                        { $1::$2                    }
```

When I pass this to fsyacc I get a list of shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflicts. An example shift/reduce conflict is

```
state 11: shift/reduce error on PLUS
```

The output from fsyacc for state 11 is:

```
state 11:
  items:
    Expr -> Expr . 'TIMES' Expr
    Expr -> Expr . 'PLUS' Expr
    ExprList -> Expr . ExprList

  actions:
    action 'EOF' (noprec):   reduce ExprList --> 
    action 'LPAR' (explicit left 10000):   shift 6
    action 'RPAR' (noprec):   reduce ExprList --> 
    action 'COMMA' (noprec):   reduce ExprList --> 
    action 'PLUS' (explicit left 9998):   shift 13
    action 'TIMES' (explicit left 9999):   shift 12
    action 'NAME' (noprec):   shift 14
    action 'CSTINT' (noprec):   shift 5
    action 'error' (noprec):   reduce ExprList --> 
    action '#' (noprec):   reduce ExprList --> 
    action '$$' (noprec):   reduce ExprList --> 

  immediate action: <none>
 gotos:
    goto Expr: 11
    goto ExprList: 16
```

It has been a while since I took a course in compiler theory, so while I kind of know what shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflicts are, I am not used to thinking about them. In particular, I don't see how reducing on `PLUS` could lead to a valid parse. All in all, any insight into one or more of the following questions would be highly appreciated:

1. Why is my grammar seemingly ambiguous?
2. Can I fix it using precedence and/or associativity rules or, if not,
3. Do I need to rewrite the grammar, and if so, roughly, how do I do it?
4. Is yacc a suitable tool for a construct like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Why is my grammar seemingly ambiguous?**

Your grammar *is* ambiguous. It's not an illusion.

Suppose f is a function.

```
f  x + 7
```

Is that `f(x) + 7` or `f(x+7)`?. Your grammar produces both.

IIRC, function application binds very tightly and associates to the left. So the above expression should parse as `f(x) + 7`.

**2. Can I fix it using precedence and/or associativity rules, or if not,**

You can disambiguate function application with precedence and associativity rules; you just need to declare a precedence for it with `%prec`. However, it ends up looking a bit ugly and ...

**3. Do I need to rewrite the grammar, and if so, roughly, how do I do it?**

... I don't believe it is correct to represent function application as `Name ExprList`. It's a lot cleaner if you curry the arguments one at a time, at least while building the AST, and it looks prettier if you do it in the grammar rather than with precedence rules, which really weren't designed for invisible operators. See below.

**4. Is yacc a suitable tool for a construct like this?**

Sure, why not?

Here are two working (as far as I know) yacc grammars. The first uses precedence declarations for everything; the second separates out function application, which I think is cleaner:

```
// grammar1.y:

%left '+'
%left '*'
%left ATOM ';' '(' ')'

%%

program: /* empty */           { $$ = ""; }
       | program statement ';' { std::cout << $2 << std::endl; }
       | program ';'
       ;

statement: expr
         ;

expr: ATOM
    | '(' expr ')'             { $$ = $2; }
    | expr expr %prec ATOM     { $$ = '(' + $1 + ' ' + $2 + ')'; }
    | expr '+' expr            { $$ = "(+ " + $1 + ' ' + $3 + ')'; }
    | expr '*' expr            { $$ = "(* " + $1 + ' ' + $3 + ')'; }
    ;
```

---

```
// grammar2.y

%token ATOM

%left '+'
%left '*'

%%

program: /* empty */           { $$ = ""; }
       | program statement ';' { std::cout << $2 << std::endl; }
       | program ';'
       ;

statement: expr
         ;

term : ATOM
     | '(' expr ')'             { $$ = $2; }
     ;

apply: term
     | apply term              { $$ = '(' + $1 + ' ' + $2 + ')'; }
     ;

expr : apply
     | expr '+' expr            { $$ = "(+ " + $1 + ' ' + $3 + ')'; }
     | expr '*' expr            { $$ = "(* " + $1 + ' ' + $3 + ')'; }
     ;
```